# What are tactics for a Witch Doctor to use against Invulnerable Minion packs?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

Invulnerable Minion packs have been very challenging for me while soloing Hell.

Generally I've been using Haunt and Poison Darts with Splinters for my single target damage, but Splinters tends to get blocked by the invulnerable minions, making positioning very important.

I'm not looking for specific builds, but rather specific tactics for a variety of builds, so that I can pick one to match whatever build I'm using.

Comment: +1. Invulnerable Minions are the single toughest thing for me to deal with, even in Inferno, with my WD. I've still not found a solution.

Comment: Have you tried some of his attacks that arc?  Something like Firebomb?

Comment: @agent86 I've played with Firebomb against them a little bit, but the problem isn't so much dealing enough damage to the main elite as much as it dealing enough damage to the main elite whilst kiting a bunch of invulnerable guys that bring the pain =/.

Comment: Note that Blizzard has stated that [they are looking in to tweaking pet AI to cause pets to automatically ignore any immune/shielded mobs](http://www.diablofans.com/blizz-tracker/topic/225709-35-small-improvements-for-diablo-3/). Coupled with the upcoming changes to pets to help scaling, this may go a long way towards adding a new tactic to deal with Invulnerable Minions packs.

Comment: Invulnerable Minions is being retired in 1.04, so this question should become just a historical artifact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an army, which means dogs, fetish and that big dude, use vision quest, combined with zombie bears, and spirit walk with more duration.    While getting an army that wil strike the immune foes you will have 3 cooldown, use zombie wall or grasp of hands to slow the immune foes. The you will get 4 cooldowns. Use spirit walk and attack the boss with full load of bears, you can also do the same but instead of using spirit walk at the bigning, attack the boss untill it unjured, then use spirit walk and countinue attacking.     For boosting this Mathod u can use big bad voodo

Comment: Hi @Moshe, welcome to the site. If you'd like to add more information to an existing answer you have posted, please use the "Edit" link located in the bottom left corner of the post. :) This will allow you insert more information without double-posting.

Comment: Thx it was a mistake since I wasn't sure it was posted

Comment: The zombie dogs, fetish army, and gargantuan don't seem particularly effective (and I wasn't really looking for complete builds, as I said in my question), but the generic "VQ + bears" model, with all variants, seems effective.  In other words, "spamming zombie bears" is an effective tactic against invulnerable minions.  There have to be other viable tactics, though, don't there?